# Need advice for making a Grid with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to use Java Swing to create a Grid that allows me to access specific panels if I need to. The frame pulls up but there are no panels. I would like some advice on how to make the panels display in the frame while still allowing me to access the specific panel through the two dimensional array.

```
x=0;
y=0;
z=0;

JPanel[][] coordinate = new JPanel[5][5];
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

frame.setSize(550,550);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizable(false);

panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));

for(int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
    if(z == 5) {
        z = 0;
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
        coordinate[x][y] = new JPanel();
        coordinate[x][y].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 10));
        panel.add(coordinate[x][y]);
    z++;
    x++;
}
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: Move the call to `setVisible` to after the call to `frame.add(panel)`.  Understand, Swing is lazy, if you modify the UI while it's already realised on the screen, you will need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you changed

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre].